# Missing service warning when uisng form type phpstorm

Tags: forms, symfony

When i create form using from type i get missing service warning. Everything works but warning is annoying and it pops up every time i commit changes to git repository.

UserType form:

`class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username', TextType::class)
            ->add('password', PasswordType::class);
    }
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Users'));
    }
}`

Form creation:

`$form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user)
                ->add('newPass', PasswordType::class, array('mapped' => false))
                ->add('confirmPass', PasswordType::class, array('mapped' => false))
                ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Change password'))`

where annoying warning happens

`$newPass = $form->get('newPass')->getData();`

I don't get any warnings if make form via 
`$form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)`

EDIT:

image of the warning

[image: missing service warning]

Comment: You should include the warning in your question, makes it easier to see whats wrong.

Comment: i have added image of the warning

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20190704/phpstorm-symfony2-missing-service-warning

Comment: already tried that, it didn't work for me